# PHP only writes first 276 characters to file

Tags: php, image, jpeg, sfml

This is the code I run on the server. I'm using C++ to read a .jpg localy and then post it with SFML in a single string. The post is apparently received by the server since content length is the same as the file size. When it comes to writing to the file however, the string seems to get shortened to just 276 characters. Last character written is %, the character after that should be & (when files are opened in notepad++), since SFML can't post files in forms I have to do it this way. Why are the files getting cut off while the string surely arrived to the server?

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value)
{
    if(strcmp(strtolower($header),"content-length")==0)
    {
        $length=intval($value);
        echo $value;
    }
}
$file=fopen("file".".txt","w");
fwrite($file,$_POST["file"],$length);
fclose($file);
```

the alternative PHP index(also doesn't work - there is no $_FILES["file"] variable upon posting):http://pastebin.com/edP6VXCr

the C++ code that I use to send: http://pastebin.com/uCaRe9X5

Comment: Please check that `echo $length` yields the same answer as `echo $value` and post a redacted version of the C++ program source. Additionally, I'm uncertain at what you mean with "can't post files in forms".

Comment: all three lengths are the same. What I meant by can't post files:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp SFML apparently can't use file as a field in submiting the content.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$_POST` with [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). Additionally, you should use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

EDIT: to further expand the comments below, try using:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/somewhere/on/the/disk');
```

Comment: I have made another file that does use files, but SFML can't upload files, nor can I do that without cURL can I?

Comment: Post PHP code: you should use something like `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/somewhere');`. If you posted C++ code, it might be easier to solve your problem. Yes, cURL is fine, use `curl -X POST`

Comment: I know about cURL, however I want to code it on my own without using cURL, since it requires to many aditional dll files.
here's the part that opens the image and sends it:
http://pastebin.com/uCaRe9X5

Comment: Your content-type is wrong. And subsequently your HTTP body. Use `Content-type: multipart/form-data` and prepare a proper multipart HTTP body if you want to upload files to PHP. It would be a better idea though not to have to care about an already solved problem, and just use a working copy of cURL.

Comment: Thanks Sven, but I tried that, but I don't quite get how I'm supposed to prepare multipart HTTP body, since I couldn't find any information...